# How can I disable config processing in Git?

Tags: git

I'm writing a script to run git on a system with a given version of git installed, but I need it to be hermetic, so that the script behaves exactly the same way regardless of any `gitconfig` files.

How can I tell git to **avoid** processing all config files?

Comment: Note that besides the accepted answer (which is probably what you need here), Git also has "plumbing" vs "porcelain" commands, and plumbing commands don't change their behavior based on Git configs, so for scripts you generally want to use those plumbing commands.

Comment: @torek: Thanks, yeah I'm aware of that actually. In my case that wasn't an adequate substitute but it's something I definitely use when I can.

Comment: Why was the accepted answer deleted?!

Comment: I have no idea, and it doesn't seem to me to have been appropriate to delete it. Not sure how to flag this for SO moderators...? (I tried to undelete and SO didn't permit me to vote on it)

Comment: @torek: I flagged the post to ask. They responded. They say the post was ChatGPT-generated and that's why it was deleted!

Comment: Interesting. I suppose that it's possible that it was ChatGPT, but it's also correct (modulo some odd formatting typos).